# SQL Select & Join Tables to display results

Tags: mysql, sql

I've just started learning about databases and SQL, and I've been working on a problem that I just can't quite nail. This is what I'm trying to do, given two tables called CHARTER and CUSTOMER:

```
Give the relational algebra statement (or SQL) as well as the table that would 
result from applying SELECT & JOIN relational operators to the CHARTER and 
CUSTOMER tables to return only the CHAR_TRIP, CUS_LNAME and CHAR_DESTINATION 
attributes for charters flown by pilot 109. 

Note that 109 is sometimes the pilot and other times the co-pilot. 
Display all these flights.
```

This is the SQL that I've tried:

```
select CHAR_TRIP, CUS_LNAME, CHAR_DESTINATION from CHARTER natural join CUSTOMER where CHARTER.CHAR_PILOT and CHARTER.CHAR_COPILOT="109";
```

But this just doesn't seem to give me what I want; I should be getting 6 records, but I'm only getting 3. I figured that it may be due to something in the SQL. Have I overlooked something with my code?

Comment: You should show us sample data.  The answer given below may be reasonable in the absence of data.

Comment: You tagged the question with both mysql and sql server. Which of those database platforms are you using?

Comment: @SamM My mistake, it should be MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if Mysql has some special syntax, but try separating the WHERE conditions:

```
select CHAR_TRIP, CUS_LNAME, CHAR_DESTINATION 
from CHARTER natural join CUSTOMER 
where CHARTER.CHAR_PILOT ="109" 
or CHARTER.CHAR_COPILOT="109";
```

I changed the second one to an `or` since 109 can be either the main pilot or the co-pilot.

Comment: This did it! Thanks!

Comment: Great, no problem :)  I believe the line `where CHARTER.CHAR_PILOT` is testing whether `CHARTER.CHAR_PILOT` is `true`.